# how install angular-xeditable in mean js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs, angular-xeditable

i've been tried to install angular-xeditable  (http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#) in meanjs (meanjs.org), but after download with bower, I can't reference the javascript files in layout.html. And that's supposed must be added automatically.

```
<!--Application JavaScript Files-->
{% for jsFile in jsFiles %}<script type="text/javascript" src="{{jsFile}}"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

So, anyone with the same problem?

Comment: the x-editable component doesn't really directly have anything to do with the server side implementation (personally I don't do any server side templating as I'd rather have a decoupled service and client layers).  Does jsFiles for sure contain the right reference to the xeditable distribution js file?  Also have you included the dependency in the angular module definition?  Would need to see more code to know what's wrong here.

Comment: I found the solution. As you said all problem is how reference the angular-xeditable.js. Mean.js use config/env/all.js  for assets configuration.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is assets reference. 
Meanjs  use config/env/all.js for assets configuration and those are injected in layout.server.view.html.

That's is the rigth way to include reference.